# JPA many-to-many saves duplicate entities

Tags: java, spring, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

I have difficulties with JPA many-to-many unidirectional relationship. The problem is that duplicate Label entities are created in DB even if they are the same. For performance reason the @Id is a generated number and not Label.label. The connected problem is that findByLabel() does not find the two notes.

I read many articles and examples and I think I have similar code, but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Spring Boot, H2, Spring Data JPA. I am looking for non-XML, pure Java annotation solution.

Repository:

```java
public interface NoteRepository extends CrudRepository<Note, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT a from Note a where ?1 member of a.labels")
    List<Note> findByLabel(Label label); }
```

Label:

```java
@Entity
public class Label {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "label_id")
    private Long labelId;

    private String label;

    protected Label() {
    }

    public Label(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public Long getLabelId() {
        return labelId;
    }

    public void setLabelId(Long labelId) {
        this.labelId = labelId;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Label)) return false;

        Label label1 = (Label) o;

        return getLabel().equals(label1.getLabel());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getLabel());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Label{" +
                "labelId=" + labelId +
                ", label='" + label + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Note:

```java
@Entity
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "note_id")
    private Long noteId;

    private String note;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Note_Label",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "NoteId",
                    referencedColumnName = "note_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "LabelId",
                    referencedColumnName = "label_id"))
    private Set<Label> labels;


    protected Note() {
    }

    public Note(String note, Set<Label> labels) {
        this.note = note;
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    public Note(String note) {
        this(note, null);
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }


    public Long getNoteId() {
        return noteId;
    }

    public void setNoteId(Long noteId) {
        this.noteId = noteId;
    }

    public Set<Label> getLabels() {
        return labels;
    }

    public void setLabels(Set<Label> labels) {
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note{" +
                "note='" + note + '\'' +
                ", labels='" + labels + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Note)) return false;

        Note note1 = (Note) o;

        if (!getNote().equals(note1.getNote())) return false;
        return getLabels() != null ? getLabels().equals(note1.getLabels()) : note1.getLabels() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getNote() != null ? getNote().hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (getLabels() != null ? getLabels().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test fails:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class NoteRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private NoteRepository repository;


    @Test
    public void findByLabel() throws Exception {

        String labelAString = "labelA";

        Label labelA = new Label(labelAString);
        Label labelA1 = new Label(labelAString);
        Label labelB = new Label("labelB");
        Label labelC = new Label("labelC");

        Note note1 = new Note(
                "note1", new HashSet<Label>(Arrays.asList(
                labelA, labelB)));

        Note note2 = new Note(
                "note2", new HashSet<Label>(Arrays.asList(
                labelA1, labelC)));

        repository.deleteAll();


        repository.save(note1);
        repository.save(note2);


        List<Note> actualNotes = repository.findByLabel(labelA);

        System.out.println(actualNotes);


        assertTrue(actualNotes.size() == 2);
        assertTrue(actualNotes.containsAll(Arrays.asList(note1, note2)));

    }

}
```

Comment: You are creating two separate Label instances and giving them the same "labelA" string value. If you want them to be the same, you need to pass in the same instance, or change your save method so that when it gets a new note, it first looks up any referenced labels using the label string.  Otherwise, if the instance passed in doesn't have an ID, it will result in an insert.  If you want an exception in this case, mark the label string as being unique - @Column(name="LABEL", unique=true). The database will then throw an exception if a duplicate is inserted

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I don't understand how can I achieve this solution, to change the save method so that it will look up persisted labels. Can this be done automatically by calling noterepository.merge or adding a different cascading setting? I am new to spring data jpa but I think that my data model with A having a set of B's must be very common, so Hibernate should have some ready-made template...?

Comment: @Chris can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

the right code:

```
@Test
public void saveAndGet() throws Exception {

    String labelAString = "labelA";

    Label labelA = new Label(labelAString);
    Label labelA1 = new Label(labelAString);
    Label labelB = new Label("labelB");
    Label labelC = new Label("labelC");

    repository.save(labelA);
    System.out.println(labelA.getLabelId());
    repository.save(labelB);

    Iterable<Label> all = repository.findAll();

    all.forEach(p ->{
        System.out.println(p.getLabel());
        System.out.println(p.getLabelId());
    });

}
```